# Как задать внутреннюю тень для геометрической фигуры с текстом внутри?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть ли способ задать внутреннюю тень для геометрической фигуры с текстом внутри?

Вот чего мне нужно добиться:

[image]

Я использовал код отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730055/required-pentagon-shape-with-right-direction-css-and-html

Если фигура состоит из дива и треугольника (вариант ниже), я могу задать тень только для дива. Но даже если бы я смог задать тень треугольнику - граница между фигурами стала бы видна.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 125px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #4275FF;

  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 75px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 75px solid transparent;
  border-left: 25px solid #4275FF;
  right: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Если использовать способ с swg, я могу создать внутреннюю тень с помощью box-shadow, но трреугольная часть фигуры опять же не будет отбрасывать тень. (И к тому же изменять пропорции фигуры в этом случае неудобно).

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #4275FF;
  
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M0,0 h125 l25,75 l-25,75 h-125z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <foreignObject clip-path="url(#shape)" width="100%" height="100%">
    <div></div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пробуй так: `box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #ddd;`

Answer (score 0):

**Вот так вроде бы**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div.bullet {
  width: 130px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 15px;
  line-height: 23px;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px #000 inset;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 28% 0, 60% 0%, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 36% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 28% 0, 60% 0%, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 36% 100%, 0 100%);
  transition: all .5s;
}
div.bullet:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px blue inset;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="bullet">
  <div class="date">
    <span>23 12 2010</span>
    <span>freeday</span>
  </div>
</div>
```